# Swing:the role of action listener

Tags: java, swing

# In the problem which i am posting,in this i am unable to understand the code mentioned on line 1 and line 2, As what i know about them is that they are used to set the action listener for the button but the thing which is most confusing for me is that in the syntax sated on the line 1 and line 2 as, {JB1.addActionListener(this)} in this what is the role of "this".....so please tell the basic behind this.And how this whole syntax works...in detail. #

```
 import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.*;



    public class frametest1_1 implements ActionListener
    {
        JLabel JL;
        public frametest1_1()
        {
            //create a JFrame container
            JFrame JF=new JFrame("A BUTTON");

            //Frame Layout This is contained in Java .awt.*;  "ON USING THIS OPTION OUR BUTTON AND OTHER COMPONENT ARE ADJUSTED IN THE FRAME AUTOMATICALLY"
            JF.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            //set the size of the container
            JF.setSize(200, 200);

            //set visible
            JF.setVisible(true);

            //make button
            JButton JB1=new JButton("FIRST");
            JButton JB2=new JButton("SECOND");

            //add button to the JFrame container
            JF.add(JB1);
            JF.add(JB2);

            //Create and add Label to the JFrame container
            JL=new JLabel("PRESS A BUTTON");
            JF.add(JL);

            //set action command :now this will help in determining that which button is presses, is it FIRST or SECOND
            JB1.setActionCommand("one");
            JB2.setActionCommand("two");

            //The action responded is added to the actionlistener
            JB1.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); // line 1
            JB2.addActionListener((ActionListener) this); // line 2
        }   

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {

            if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("one"))
                JL.setText("First Button Pressed");     // to set text on the label
            else
                JL.setText("Second button Pressed");    // to set the text on the label

        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    new frametest1_1();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Consider that `Listener is someone who reacts to some action`.

**2.**`ActionListener` is an **Interface** which has a **call back method**, named `actionPerformed`, inside which is the code **that will run when certain action is done on the controller.**

**3.** This line `JB1.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);` means as follows

```
   JB1 - Button
   ActionListener - Interface
   addActionListener - Registering the Button with the Listener.
```

**4.** `addActionListener` will **bind/register** the `Button` with the `Listener` (here its ActionListener).

**5.** In an `MVC` architecture `Button is the controller`, when certain action is done on it, then who all are to be informed to do certain things is done by registering it to the  listener.

**6.** And this Listener will have the `callback` method which will be **overridden by the class that implements the listener.**

**7.** Moreover in your example, you can also do it like this...
       `JB1.addActionListener(this);`

Comment: thanks.....but let me know one thing that the parameter which i am passing "this" is basically the instance of the class frametest1_1.if instead of "this" i pass an object of this class after creating it like frametest1_1 obj=new frametest1_1();, than would it be wrong

Comment: "this" here means "the current object", you are passing the instance of the class which has implemented Runnable interface, You can pass the object of the class inplace of this, But then you must be sure that you are instantiating `the SAME OBJECT TO WHICH YOU HAVE ATTACHED THE listener from main() FUNCTION`. Its possible when you apply Singleton Pattern, only one object is created in this case.

Answer (score 1):

'this' refers to the current instance of the enclosing class (frametest1_1), the instance constructed in the run() method.

Some further reading on 'this':
[Using the this Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score -1):

Provided code is terribly ugly from object-oriented design point of view - hence your confusion. It's definitely bad idea to have one class responsible for:

- containing main method
- holding references to `JFrame` components (i.e. `JLabel`)
- implementation of `ActionListener` concept

thus violating [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), though such ugly examples can be found even in official tutorials on Swing.

Slightly better implementation of exactly the same functionality would be the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class frametest1_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runFrameTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void runFrameTest() {
        //create a JFrame container
        JFrame JF=new JFrame("A BUTTON");

        //Frame Layout This is contained in Java .awt.*;  "ON USING THIS OPTION OUR BUTTON AND OTHER COMPONENT ARE ADJUSTED IN THE FRAME AUTOMATICALLY"
        JF.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //set the size of the container
        JF.setSize(200, 200);

        //set visible
        JF.setVisible(true);

        //make button
        JButton JB1=new JButton("FIRST");
        JButton JB2=new JButton("SECOND");

        //add button to the JFrame container
        JF.add(JB1);
        JF.add(JB2);

        //Create and add Label to the JFrame container
        final JLabel JL=new JLabel("PRESS A BUTTON");
        JF.add(JL);

        //set action command :now this will help in determining that which button is presses, is it FIRST or SECOND
        JB1.setActionCommand("one");
        JB2.setActionCommand("two");

        ActionListener labelUpdater = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {               
                if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("one"))
                    JL.setText("First Button Pressed");     // to set text on the label
                else
                    JL.setText("Second button Pressed");    // to set the text on the label             
            }
        };
        //The action responded is added to the actionlistener
        JB1.addActionListener(labelUpdater); // line 1
        JB2.addActionListener(labelUpdater); // line 2
    }

}
```

Hope this helps in understanding ...

Comment: You are giving OO lessons by providing an anti-OO pattern using a static method that initialize the GUI. You should rather have an instance that itself creates the GUI in either the constructor either an instance method. `static` is OO-programming worst ennemy!

Comment: I agree that my code is not 100% perfect from OO point of view, though I tried to explain only how to correctly use `ActionListener`s in Swing, not generally how to structure Swing-based applications. Concerning `static` method used here - I used it here for 2 reasons: 1. this example is too small to create separate classes/instances here 2. in order not to pollute `main` method with logic.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer: "Provided code is terribly ugly from object-oriented design point of view", so I would assume that you will provide something which is not ugly from OO design point of view. Secondly, if you consider your example to be too small to follow OO design, this makes the question as valid as your answer. Finally, from an MVC point of view, this is perfectly acceptable. You have a controller class (frametest_1_1) which creates the View and listens to view event. I think that the user is confused mainly about the usage of `this`and `ActionListener`.

Comment: `Controller creating the View` is perfectly acceptable from `MVC` point of view?

Comment: I think no one cares if a sample with `static` is written for a short demo. `main(String[] args)` is neither my nor OOP enemy in this case, sorry.

Comment: @Yura: yes, I don't see who else would do that. Take a look at this schema that summarize pretty well the MVC design pattern: http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=uvf&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&biw=1600&bih=782&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=OIIG64NCKJ6UtM:&imgrefurl=http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/MVC-detailed.html&docid=XpoTAC1o4s6DPM&imgurl=http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/images/mvc-structure-generic.gif&w=550&h=385&ei=KpwOUPL3FuO90QWdi4GIAw&zoom=1

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv The answer is actualy insisting on the OO-design but it does not respect it, so for me the answer is self-contradictory. Moreover, using an instance is not more complex than using `static` and does not require more lines of code. So for me, if for the same "price" you can post an answer with a better design, you should choose to follow proper design patterns. `main` is actually the only method that you have to keep `static`.

Comment: As per provided article, it's not mentioned anywhere that `Controller` creates the `View` i.e. acts as `Factory` for `View` because it's not the responsibility of `Controller`. The `single` responsibility of `Controller` is to only `map user actions to model updates` as per image. I'll post separate question concerning this on SO in the near future and invite you to discuss this, because comments are not the best place to speak about this :)